# - Design Pattern (Discussion) Address Lookuptables to compress on chain storage of `PubKeys`

Tags: on-chain, lookup-tables, architecture, discussion

Reading up on ALT's, A certain usecase came to mind, where in a program if for some arbitary reason i want to store a list of pubkeys(32bytes) say in the 10,000 on chain, wdnt using ALT allow me to compress `32*10000` into `(storing address of corresponding lookup table(32) + 8*10000)`. I understand the main usage of alt is to overcome the tx size limit of the udp packet to allow more accounts, but wasnt sure if the above usage is an anti-pattern or has any caveats that i am missing out on.
Then inside the programs instead of Storing all the pubkeys in a Vec once can just store Vec instead where the u8 refrences the index of the corresponding key in the lookuptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely the correct use case! There's a few caveats though.

- Even with LUTs transactions are still capped at using 256 accounts at most.
- Additionally, each LUT can only store at most 256 addresses, so you wouldn't be able to fit 10k addresses in one LUT.

Source for all this can be found [here](https://solana.com/docs/advanced/lookup-tables).

Comment: Hey I understand the caveats you pointed out, the way our program is architected is there is a global lookuptabla whose address is derived via a counter, every 256 new addresses that counter is increased and a new lookup table is created, we have user accounts that just store indexes into those global tables with increasing index count for example 50 represents the 50%256th index in the 50/256  counter derived global lookup table where as 300 represents the  300%256 index in the lookup table derived with a counter of 300/256.

Comment: What I wanted to know was if the index a particular pub key  is associated with inside a lookup table something one can find  onchain given the lookup table account to the program ?

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand, but this should just be a matter of providing the correct look up table and then checking for the value at i%256 inside that table.